# Trying to connect to my SQL Database but throws errors

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am getting {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"} looked over everything and it looks good to me, what am I missing? The point of this android project I am working on is to insert an email address within a EditText on the app which will create that new user + a user id in my database.

create_user.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new user row
 * All user details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['uid']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {

        $uid = $_POST['uid'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/DB_Connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO USERS(uid, email) VALUES('$uid', '$email')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "User successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

this is my DB_Connect.php

```
db_connect.php
<?php

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/DB_Config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

This is my Login Activity. Where a user would enter their email address then send that information to the database with that email address and create a user id.

package com.wny.wecare;

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender.SendIntentException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.wny.wecare.R;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.model.people.Person;
import com.wny.wecare.handler.JSONParser;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener,
ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    Button btnLogin;

    // url to create new user
    private static String url_create_user = "http://infinitycodeservices.com/create_user.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    // Profile pic image size in pixels
    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * A flag indicating that a PendingIntent is in progress and prevents us
     * from starting further intents.
     */
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    private boolean mSignInClicked;

    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;

    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;

    public static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback sessionStatusCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, sessionStatusCallback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create Button
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);
        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.gplus);

        // Edit Text
        txtName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llProfile);


        // Button click listeners
        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);  

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
        .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to resolve any signin errors
     * */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                mIntentInProgress = true;
                mConnectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                mIntentInProgress = false;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }


        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this,
                    0).show();
            return;
        }

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            // Store the ConnectionResult for later usage
            mConnectionResult = result;

            if (mSignInClicked) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to
                // resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

    }


    private UserInfoChangedCallback createUserInfoChangedCallback() {
        return new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {

                if (user != null) {


                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
    }




    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
        // TODO switch by session state
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, int responseCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // The Facebook login flow requires the users to transition out of, and
        // back into, this Activity.
        // That's why we need the onActiviyResult method :)
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode,
                resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
                mSignInClicked = false;
            }

            mIntentInProgress = false;

            if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        // Get user's information
        getProfileInformation();

        // Update the UI after signin
        updateUI(true);

    }



    /**
     * Updating the UI, showing/hiding buttons and profile layout
     * */
    private void updateUI(boolean isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            btnSignIn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            llProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fetching user's information names, email, profile pic
     * */
    private void getProfileInformation() {
        try {
            if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null) {
                Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi
                        .getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
                String personName = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
                String personPhotoUrl = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
                String personGooglePlusProfile = currentPerson.getUrl();
                String email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);

                Log.e(TAG, "Name: " + personName + ", plusProfile: "
                        + personGooglePlusProfile + ", email: " + email
                        + ", Image: " + personPhotoUrl);

                txtName.setText(personName);
                txtEmail.setText(email);

                // by default the profile url gives 50x50 px image only
                // we can replace the value with whatever dimension we want by
                // replacing sz=X
                personPhotoUrl = personPhotoUrl.substring(0,
                        personPhotoUrl.length() - 2)
                        + PROFILE_PIC_SIZE;



            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Person information is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        updateUI(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Button on click listener
     * */
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // creating new user in background thread
        new CreateNewUser().execute();
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.gplus:
            // Signin button clicked
            signInWithGplus();
            break;


        }
    }

    /**
     * Sign-in into google
     * */
    private void signInWithGplus() {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            mSignInClicked = true;
            resolveSignInError();
        }
    }



    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new user
     * */
    class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging In..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating User
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();


            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));


            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create user url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_user,
                    "POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created user
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create user
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once done
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }



        /**
         * Background Async task to load user profile picture from url
         * */
        private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
            ImageView bmImage;

            public LoadProfileImage(ImageView bmImage) {
                this.bmImage = bmImage;
            }

            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
                String urldisplay = urls[0];
                Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
                try {
                    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
                    mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return mIcon11;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (Session.getActiveSession() != null || Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()){
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: check your DB and see what are the fields there that are **Not Null**. And you can't leave null that field and in `users` table `primary key` for example (id) would be `auto increment`

Comment: The portion of your code that generates the error only occurs when `isset($_POST['uid']) && isset($_POST['email'])` is false it looks like, which is before any of your DB interactions

Comment: both fields are NOT NULL and id has AUTO_INCREMENT and is Primary

Comment: Data sent by POST method? Field's name are uid and email? Check `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: @ScottDeCota sorry, now i got what really the question is, plz ignore my answer about adding `$`, now what JRLambert and trzyeM  say, is correct, the data is not sent to the page from the mobile app, why don't you post the Java code related to do the httpPost?

Comment: Because I would figure that the java part wouldn't really effect the outcome of the response. Going to the website directly would/should give me {"success":0,"message":"User successfully created"} or am I wrong?

Comment: I was told the way I am testing is false. I am testing as a POST method than a GET method which would then give me the results I was looking for.

Comment: @Yazan I added the information above for my Java class

Comment: @ScottDeCota yes you can't test a post request within a browser URL, because you need to send data as POST, and brwoser URL sends a GET request  however, at your code you are adding only `email` to `params` so `uid` is still missing., add another line contains uid `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", strUid));`

Comment: though, uid should not be sent from client, because it should be unique, and server only can generate unique values, commonly it's the primary key of the user record, which in most cases an auto-increament or server side generated value, unless your business requires client to send the uid,

Comment: I have inserted the params.add and got this "strUid cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: strUid is an example of the variable name, you should declare and fill that variable, it looks you need to know better what exactly you want and read more about http calls, params, database and backend in general ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I couldn't figure out the multiple errors so I went a different route using GET. Also had to change my JSONParcer.java. Throws no errors and goes right to the MainActivity class...BUT! This method will create a new column with an uid with no data/email address

Update on create_user.php

```
<?php



/*

* Following code will get all agencies matching the query

* Returns essential details

* An agency is identified by agency id

*/



require("DB_Link.php");



//query database for matching agency

$query = "INSERT INTO user(Email) VALUES('$email')";



$email = ($_GET['Email']);



//Execute insert query

try {

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO user(Email) VALUES('$email')");

    $stmt->execute(array('email' => $email));

}

catch (PDOException $ex)    {

    $response["success"] = 0;

    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";

    die('Error!: ' . json_encode($ex->getMessage()));;

}

//Execute select query on success

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE Email = :email");

$stmt->execute(array('email' => $email));



//Retrieve all found rows and add to array

$result = $stmt->FETCHALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

echo json_encode($result);


?>
```

Also an Update on my LoginActivity.java

```
package com.wny.wecare;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.wny.wecare.handler.JSONParser;


public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText inputEmail;
    Button btnLogin;

    public String strUid;
    // url to create new user
    private static String url_create_user = "http://infinitycodeservices.com/create_user.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);

        // Edit Text
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);


        // Create button
        Button btnCreateUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);

        // button click event
        btnCreateUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new user in background thread
                new CreateNewUser().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Create new User
     * */
    class CreateNewUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Logging in..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Creating User
         * */
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // Check for success tag
            int success;

            String email = findViewById(R.id.email).toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("uid", strUid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

          // Creating JSON Parser object
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            Log.d("request!", "starting");
            // getting product detail s by making HTTP request
            JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(
                    url_create_user , params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

            // json success tag
           //  success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
           //  if (success == 1) 
            {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                //SAVE
                SharedPreferences ui = getSharedPreferences("UserInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edUi = ui.edit();
                edUi.putString("uid", strUid);
                edUi.putString("email", email);
                edUi.commit();

                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();

                // Returns Toast "Login success!"
                //return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);


            }

            return null;

        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * *
         */
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

JSONParcer.java

```
package com.wny.wecare.handler;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser { 
    static InputStream iStream = null; 
    static JSONArray jarray = null; 
    static String json = ""; 

    public JSONParser() { } 

    public JSONArray getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) { 
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(); 
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url); 

        try { 
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet); 
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine(); 
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode(); 
            if (statusCode == 200) { 
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity(); 
                InputStream content = entity.getContent(); 
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content)); 
                String line; 
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) { 
                    builder.append(line); 
                } 
            } 
            else { Log.e("==>", "Failed to download file"); 
            } 
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        catch (IOException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        // Parse String to JSON object 
        try { 
            jarray = new JSONArray( builder.toString()); 
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) { 
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString()); 
        }
        // return JSON Object 
        return jarray; 
    } 
}
```